# How to get the tracing logs for Dynamics CRM 2015 online reports

Tags: dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working on migrating Dynamics CRM 2013 on prem to Dynamics CRM 2015 online update 1 and have prepared a report that has a child report as well. After successfully uploading the reports and setting up parent/child report relationship. I get **"The Report cannot be displayed (rsProcessingAborted)"** when I run the report. In case of On-Prem we could look into trace logs, what can we do in case of CRM 2015 online now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only thing you can do is to get in touch with MS Support to recheck what's wrong with your report.

Comment: Wow, that's gonna be quite a challenge ahead of us. I hope Microsoft can make this available in coming updates.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to try to locate where you have an error. Like Delete all controls, upload, check. If you have errors - this control generates it. If no - add new control. e.t.c. Unfortunately for now only try/error/success path is available.